# Register Machine code for Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: programming-languages, recurrence-relation, recursion

I am not sure whether this is the right place to ask this question.

I would like to write a register machine code which when given an input of n in register
1, returns (also in register 1) the nth Fibonacci number. The Fibonacci numbers are
0 (the 0th), 1 (the 1st), 1 = 0 + 1 (the 2nd), etc.

I tried to write few lines of the codes, but unable to do the recursive property of Fibonacci sequence. Here is my code:

Let A, B, C be registers.

1. (-A; 2,-)
2. (+C; 1)
3. (-C; 4,-)
4. (+B; 5)
5. (+A; 3)

I know that the fifth line is wrong but have no idea how to fix it. And I want to code to be as simple as possible (i.e. with fewest instructions). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cant read your code.

Comment: If you want us to write (or check) your program, at least give a hint on the programming language you are using.

Comment: +1 to @vonbrand Your language doesn't look standard to me ... And for your question I'm pretty sure that you will have to use conditional jump to do the recursive property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write register machine code for Fibonacci](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12339/how-to-write-register-machine-code-for-fibonacci)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code in C, which you can "compile" into your assembly language:

```
int x = 0, y = 1, z;
while (n--) {
  z = x;
  x = y;
  y += z;
}
return x;
```

After $n$ iterations of the loop, $x = F_n$ and $y = F_{n+1}$.